# Decoding pdf with winansiencoding on my iPhone

Tags: file, pdf, itext, adobe, decoder

I have a file that when I open it on my iPhone shows a bunch of encryption and data.
Producer(SautinSoft company)
/Creator(PDF Vision .Net 4.6.1.23)

```
It says winansiencoding and helvetica basefont as well in all of this before giving a body of dark diamond characters and jumbled letters  and so on.
```

So my question is if I download adobe acrobat reader app on my iPhone and I was to open this file with that would I be able to then read it? Or will it be all jumbled still then too? How do I find out what this file is and can read it? Thanks for all information and help pointing in the right direction?

Comment: %PDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<<
/Title()
/Producer(SautinSoft company)
/Creator(PDF Vision .Net 4.6.1.23)
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 3 0 R
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<<
/Type /Pages
/Kids [ 6 0 R]
/Count 1
>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<<
/ProcSet [/PDF/Text/ImageC]
/Font << /F0 5 0 R>>
/XObject << /I0 8 0 R>>
>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<<
/Type/Font
/Subtype /Type1
/Name /F0
/BaseFont /Helvetica
/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding
>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Parent 3 0 R
/Resources 4 0 R
/Contents 7 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 612.08 792.10]
>>
endobj
7 0 obj
<<
/Length 129

Comment: That is what the file starts off with in adobe? Please help it’s freezing up my files app on iPhone where I can’t do anything.

Comment: Ok so on my iPhone how could I go about changing this font I guess? Because the file is saved in files and comes up like this originally too. It says it’s a pdf.txt does that make a difference? 
 I just don’t understand why all the crazy characters and not simple words in any of my apps or anything. How would I know what to change it to in any file to make it readable? I just want to understand what it’s saying in anything lol thank you and keep it from freezing up my files app